# Angular tapping outside of input does not trigger blur

Tags: angularjs

Basically I'm using ng material and I have a set of input boxes. On iOS and Android it seems tapping outside of the boxes doesn't blur. Do I need to make a directive to listen for taps on the body to fix this or am I missing something? As far as i was aware it should just work.

Going to the [material input demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input) on an iPhone I can't get the inputs to blur when I tap outside of them.

Cheers for any light you can shed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I wrote a simple directive to blur any clicks that weren't on an input like this, issue only seemed to happen on mobile device so I'm also checking what resolution the browser is at:-

```
function blurInput($document, breakpoints, $rootScope) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("touchstart click", function (event) {
            var el = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (window.innerWidth <= breakpoints.mobile && (el && el !== 'input')) {
                $document[0].activeElement.blur();
            }
        });
    }
}
```